# How to find $(a + b)(b + c)(c + d)(d + e)(e + a)$ for a quintic

Tags: polynomials, roots

Given the polynomial:

$$10x^5+37x^4-83x^3-83x^2+37x+10$$

where $a, b, c, d, e$ are roots of the above polynomial and $a < b < c < d < e$, what is the value of $(a + b)(b + c)(c + d)(d + e)(e + a)$?
I know that you can use synthetic division to find the roots, but is there a different way to solving this problem? I've tried to do some factorization with Vieta's, but I couldn't find any representation of the expression in terms that Vieta's would fully help with this problem.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Are you familiar with the rational roots theorem? It's easy to see $x = -1$ is a solution, can you spot others?

Comment: Can you see that if $x_0\neq 0$ is a root then so is $1/x_0$? (cf. palindromic polynomials)

Comment: @Ajay I am, although I'm wondering if there's a way to find the value without explicitly finding the roots.

Comment: @Gary I didn't notice that, but I'm still stuck on how to find the desired product. As -1 is a root, then you could possibly substitute $b = 1/a$ and $d = 1/e$ to get an expression of $(a + 1/a)(1/a + -1)(-1 + 1/d)(1/d + d)(d + a)$ (although this requires the dodgy information that a is negative and d is positive)

Comment: You're better off using the rational root theorem assuming the roots are all rational numbers. Vieta's is absolutely horrible.

Comment: @Ansere The expression you want isn't fully symmetric (it has only cyclic symmetry), hence you cannot express it in terms of symmetric polynomials of the coefficients to use Vieta.

Answer (score 3):

Building on from the comments:

The coefficients of this polynomial are symmetric so if $x_0$ is a root, so is $1/x_0$ ($x = 0$ is not a root).

Now using [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs), the coefficients of $f(x)$ have $2$ sign changes, and $f(-x) = -10x^5 + 37x^4 + 83x^3 - 83x^2 - 37x + 10$ has $3$ sign changes. Since the question tells you that the roots can be ordered, all of the roots must be real. Hence we can conclude that $f(x)$ has exactly $2$ positive roots and $3$ negative roots.

So because of the condition $a < b < c < d < e$, it turns out that $ac = 1$ (there are two negative roots which are not $-1$ and the negative roots must also multiply to $1$) and $de = 1$. From this it follows that $b = -1$, and so we need to find:

$$(a - 1)(-1 + 1/a)(1/a + d)(d + 1/d)(1/d + a)$$

Expanding this is going to be very messy, so we can use Vieta to note the sum of the roots $a - 1 + 1/a + d + 1/d = -37/10$ or $a + 1/a + d + 1/d = -27/10. \tag{1}$

Similarly, for the $x^2$ term, $-(-83/10) = 83/10$ is the sum of the product of all combinations of $3$ roots. Since $abcde = 1 \cdot 1 \cdot -1 = -1$, this is:

$$-(1/(ab) + 1/(bc) + 1/(cd) + 1/(de) + 1/(ea) + 1/(ac) + 1/(bd) + 1/(ce) + 1/(da) + 1/(be))$$

where there are ${5 \choose 3} = 10$ terms in total.

Thus:

$$-(-1/a - a + a/d + 1 + d/a + 1 - 1/d + ad  + 1/(ad) - d) = 83/10$$
$$-(1/a + a + d + 1/d) + a/d + 1 + d/a + 1 + ad + 1/(ad) = -83/10$$
$$a/d + d/a + ad + 1/(ad) = -83/10 - 27/10 - 2 = -13 \tag{2}$$

Now, if we let $a + 1/a = u$, $d + 1/d = v$, then $uv = ad + a/d + d/a + 1/(ad)$ which is exactly what we have already!

Therefore, $u + (-13)/u = -2.7$, and solving this quadratic leads to $u = -5.2, v = 2.5$ or vice versa. Solving the other two quadratics gives the roots as $-5, -1, -0.2, 0.5, 2$.

---

Addendum: Descartes' rule of signs only tells us that there can be $2$ or $0$ positive real roots, and $3$ or $1$ negative real roots. Therefore, it is possible that the roots are complex. This can happen when we have $x = -1$ as the only real root and the roots satisfy $r_1 r_2 = -1, r_3 r_4 = -1$ first, *and* also are in conjugate pairs:

[image]

The condition in the question $a < b < c < d < e$ is designed to rule out this scenario.